# Using templating and filtering in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm pretty new to Angular, and I've run into an issue. I'm hoping that there is an easy way to solve this problem.

Basically, I have a list of Appointments that I retrieve from the server.

`$scope.appointments = [{starts_at: "2015-1-1", name: "First"}, {starts_at: "2015-1-1", name: "Last"}, {starts_at: "2015-1-2", name: "Next Day"}];`

Now I'd like to show these appointments in a list. I decided that I could use `ng-repeat` + filters for this, but now I'm stuck.

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class='box'>
      <div class="list list-inset" ng-repeat="appt in appointments | filter:????>
        <div class="item" ng-click="openAppointmentModal(appt)">
          <span>Appt {{appt.name}}</span>
          <span>Starts at {{appt.starts_at}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

I wasn't sure if I could use the built-in `filterFilter` to do this, so I ended up writing my own filter `filterDateFilter`, which takes in an array, a property name, and what date you want to filter for.  I can then write something like `ng-repeat='appt in appointments | filterDate:starts_at:curDate'` where `curDate` is defined by `$scope.curDate = new Date()` in the controller.

Phew. That works, but only for filtering for whatever $scope.curDate is defined as.

Now, I want to the user to be able to swipe to the previous/next days, and show only the appointments for that day. I assume I'd have to move the `<ion-slide>` to a template, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  **What are my next steps?**

Sorry for the long post and detailed explanation, but I didn't want to just throw up a question and show no previous effort.

Comment: you need to create three ion-slide with ng-repeat. you need an array to hold that three slide. create a fiddle if you can.

Comment: @wayne what do you mean? Don't I need an infinite number of slides? And how can I change the filter based on what date I'm on?

Comment: Ah, I see. You misunderstood me, I want the user to be able to swipe for as long as he/she wants in either direction. Not just the next and previouss days

Comment: no, you create min of 3 slide, in the `$scope.slideHasChanged($index)` you need to do couple of things. update `$scope.curDate` either +1 day or -1 day. insert an object to the model you bound to ion-slide so a new slide is created. optionally you can remove one from the array so you maintain only 3 slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of ion-slide, you can use the ionic `on-slide-left` and `on-slide-right` directives to call a function you define in your controller which increments or decrements `$scope.curDate` by 1. This seems a simpler alternative to me than simulating infinite slides.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipeLeft/